# Unable to pass the correct context to isGooglePlayServicesAvailable

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have this function in my code

```
private boolean isGoogleServiceAvailable() {
    try {
        int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this); //ERROR
        if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable, this, GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
            dialog.show();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.googleMapsServiceNotAvailable, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return false;
}
```

However I am getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` exception on this line of the code:

```
int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
```

Probably due to I am not passing the context correctly.

My class declaration looks like this:

```
public class MapEngine extends Activity implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, OnItemSelectedListener {
```

I am calling the method from the `onCreate` of my main activity:

```
public class AppMain extends ListActivity{    
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main_view);

            // InitiateMap
            mapObj.isGoogleServiceAvailable();

        }
```

Can you please tell me how to pass the correct context to `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable` function?

Comment: where are you calling `isGoogleServiceAvailable()` from?

Comment: You did not provide information where you are calling the line with npe... Remeber that contex is valid after super.onCreate of activity

Comment: sorry for that, please check my updated question.

Comment: have you tried, getApplicationContext() ?

Comment: @El_Mochiq same problem even with ` getApplicationContext() `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is beacause you're using the method of an activity that's not created. Try checking the play services from the main app, before you launch the map.

```
public class AppMain extends ListActivity{    
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_view);

try {
            int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext()); //ERROR
            if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
                return true;
            }
            else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {
                Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable, AppMain.this, GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
                dialog.show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.googleMapsServiceNotAvailable, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }           



    }
```